# Javascript reading server file GET http://localhost:3000/public/uploads/goodj.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-read

I am trying to read server file in javascript in ruby on rails project.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/public/uploads/goodj.json",
    success: function (file_content) {
        console.log(file_content);
    }
});
```

And this causes error

> GET http://localhost:3000/public/uploads/goodj.json 404 (Not Found)

I think server is recognizing this request as action of controller.

What can I do to make server to understand this is request for reading file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html):

> **config.public_file_server.enabled** configures Rails to serve static
>   files from the public directory. This option defaults to true, but in
>   the production environment it is set to false because the server
>   software (e.g. NGINX or Apache) used to run the application should
>   serve static files instead. If you are running or testing your app in
>   production mode using WEBrick (it is not recommended to use WEBrick in
>   production) set the option to true. Otherwise, you won't be able to
>   use page caching and request for files that exist under the public
>   directory.

And the URL should be `/uploads/goodj.json`, not `/public/uploads/goodj.json`. So the code snippet should look like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/uploads/goodj.json",
    success: function (file_content) {
        console.log(file_content);
    }
});
```